# how to get topic name dynamically and then read from it

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a scenario where I need to read topic names dynamically. Is there any way to get names of all the topics in the domain and then read messages from them one by one?

```
     @KafkaListener(groupId="something")
     someMethod(List<topics> topics){
        switchTo(topics.get(0)){
          read messages}
        switchTo(topics.get(1)){
          read messages}
       ...
       ...
       ...
     }
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "dynamic". How many consumer threads are you expecting to start?

Answer (score 2):

All you need it is `listTopics` from [`AdminClient`](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-host:9092");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);

System.out.println(adminClient.listTopics(new ListTopicsOptions()).names().get());
```

Comment: How does this help with the consumer?

Comment: @cricket_007 OP asked about how to generate a list of topic names.

Comment: Dynamic names, not all of them *and then read messages from them one by one*

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic names?

Comment: @cricket_007 it doesn't say dynamic names but reading topic names dynamically which is completely different from what you said. As far as I understood, they want to read programmatically the name of topics and this is something you can do via AdminClient and then using the topic names to consume messages via the consumer client.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the Kafka AdminClient, it provides a couple of overload for the `listTopics` method in order to get information about all the topics in the cluster. See here for reference: https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html

Comment: How does this help with the consumer?

Comment: As already mentioned by Giorgos he was asking for getting topics name. It's not possible to do with consumer API ... but you need Admin API

Comment: So what does [`KafkaConsumer.listTopics`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#listTopics--) really do?

Comment: Provides information about all topics and related partitions in the cluster.

Answer (score -1):

Kafka Consumer can subscribe to a regex pattern...

If you need specific logic based on the name of the topic, I'd suggest you create separate methods or applications for those use cases and specify the name in the `@KafkaListener` annotation